# How can I use std::chrono or anything else to slow down my for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, c++-chrono

If I'm doing:

`for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {   cout<<i;   }`

It displays 0 through 99 immediately, how can I slow it down so that it displays one number every second? One number every half a second? This is in C++. I'm trying to make a character on my screen move based on the values of the for, but using the for loop right now moves it to the final spot immediately rather than stopping between each number.

Comment: `std::thread::sleep_for(1s);` here: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Comment: I would put that line inside my for loop I'm presuming, right before cout?

Comment: Before or after.

Comment: I'm getting a "thread has no member for sleep_for" error, any ideas?

Comment: I am sorry it's `std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);`

Comment: When your question is closed as a duplicate, the intent is that the answer to your question are available on that post. Please take the time to read that thoroughly to see if your follow up questions are answered as well.

Comment: Do I need to "join" the thread or anything afterwards?

Comment: No. It's not creating a new thread, it's just pausing execution of the single thread that's already running.